Is it possible to generate a Podfile on a Windows machine?
On my flutter project one of my dependencies require a podfile for the configuration of the ios app. However the pod file doesnt exist. I checked you need CocoaPods installed but it seems its only for macos.
Is there a way to generate a podfile on a windows machine or do you need macos for this?

If it's a new flutter project then you should have a pod file under iOS/Podfile. If not you can create it on windows as its just a file but you cant install or run the iOS pods/app without a Mac.
